# Google Calendar and Ical Synchronization

Tags: php, calendar, synchronization, google-calendar-api

I am currently working on a PHP module which generate ICS file. I would like to know if there is a way to synchronize my ICS file with a calendar like google agenda more than once every 24 hours?

I know that Google performs the synchronization once per day, but this is not frequent enough for me (example: a change in a medical appointment)

An example of my ICS file :

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-WR-CALNAME:Test
X-WR-TIMEZONE:Europe/Paris
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:uid3@host1.com
DTSTART:20150713T100000Z
DTEND:20150713T102000Z
DTSTAMP:20150711T110721Z
SUMMARY:Test
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

I know that this is a recurring question but I have not found a viable solution.